# Imperativ von „überführen“ als „in einen anderen Zustand bringen”

Tags: separable-verb, mathematics, imperative

Bei [Wahrig](http://www.wissen.de/rechtschreibung/ueberfuehren) lesen wir:

> **über**|**füh**|**ren** 〈V. 1, hat übergeführt, ugs. auch überführt; mit Akk.〉

> 1. etwas oder jmdn. ü. *(mittels Fahrzeugs an einen Ort) bringen*; der Sarg wurde in die Familiengruft in Kaiserslautern übergeführt, 〈ugs. auch〉 überführt; einen Kranken ins Krankenhaus ü.

> 2. etwas in etwas ü. *etwas in einen Zustand bringen, übergehen lassen*; eine Flüssigkeit in gasförmigen Zustand ü.

> , **über**|**füh**|**ren** 〈V. 1, hat überführt〉

> I. 〈mit Akk. und Gen.〉 jmdn. einer Sache ü. *jmdm. eine Sache nachweisen*; jmdn. eines Verbrechens, einer Schuld ü.

> II. 〈mit Akk.〉 etwas mit etwas ü. *einen Bau über etwas hinweg errichten*; eine Straße mit einer Fußgängerbrücke ü. *eine Fußgängerbrücke über eine Straße bauen, hinwegführen*

Wenn es um die Zustandsänderung geht, soll also in Schrift (wenn ich das Obige richtig verstehe und wenn es nicht umgangssprachlich sein sollte) die Vorsilbe trennbar sein: „hat übergeführt“.

Aus der Schule erinnere ich mich hingegen an die untrennbare Vorsilbe:

> Überführen Sie die Parabelgleichung […] in Normalform!

, nicht an

> Führen Sie die Parabelgleichung […] in Normalform über!

Dabei geht es jedoch ganz klar um die *Zustandsänderung* der Beschreibung der Parabel. Sind die Matheschulbücher hier nicht strikt genug oder bin ich zu stark ans Umgangssprachliche gewöhnt und meine Erinnerung ist unvollständig oder worin sonst könnte der Grund für so eine Diskrepanz liegen?

PS. Ich sehe inzwischen auch „führen Sie die […] Gleichung über in […]“ in [einem anerkannten Buch](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Partielle_Differentialgleichungen/6YGrBgAAQBAJ?hl=de&gbpv=1&dq=%22f%C3%BChren%20Sie%22%20die%20Gleichung%20in%20%22%C3%BCber%22&pg=PA107), „Warum führen Sie Gleichungssysteme in äquivalente Systeme über?“ in der [Übersetzung eines anerkannten Buches](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Lineare_Programmierung_und_Erweiterungen/zU2pBgAAQBAJ?hl=de&gbpv=1&dq=%22f%C3%BChren%20Sie%22%20die%20Gleichung%20in%20%22%C3%BCber%22&pg=PA103) und „[…], da irgend zwei Gleichungen […] in einander übergeführt werden können“ in einem [historischen Werk anerkannter Autoren](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Mathematische_Annalen/LD_WAAAAMAAJ?hl=de&gbpv=1&dq=Gleichung%20%C3%BCbergef%C3%BChrt&pg=PA315).  Wie klingt das für euch?

Answer (score 2):

[DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/%C3%BCberf%C3%BChren) beschreibt das genauso, siehe I, Ziffer 2.

Eine Google-Suche bestätigt andererseits Deine Erinnerung, eines von vielen  Beispielen (leider überwiegend in PDF-Dateien ausgelagert):

> Überführen Sie die Relation in 2NF.

Ich würde sagen, das wird immer noch so benutzt. Ich sehe folgende Möglichkeiten:

1. Wahrig und DWDS haben die Bedeutung Zustandsübergang falsch einsortiert.
2. Das gemeinte *überführen* ist ein mathematischer Fachterminus, der anderen Regeln gehorcht und in beiden Werken nicht aufgeführt ist. Dagegen spricht, dass das chemische *überführen* explizit genannt ist, meiner Einschätzung aber identisch verwendet wird.
3. (Siehe Kommentar a_donda) Das betreffende *überführen* ist gar kein Fachbegriff, sondern nicht regelkonforme Umgangssprache.

(Community-Wiki, gerne ergänzen)

Comment: es gibt noch eine Möglichkeit: DWDS und Wahrig haben Recht und "überführen" ist gar kein (allgemeingültiger) mathematischer Fachbegriff und seine Verwendung eher ugs. oder ad hoc. Z.B. In H. Weitz - Konkrete Mathematik, Springer 2018 kommt er nicht einmal vor (PDF durchsucht). Stattdesssen werden spezifische Ausdrücke je nach Vorgang verwendet wie "umformen", "ableiten", ...

Comment: ... und ich muß mich korrigieren. 3 Mal auf ~950 Seiten würd "überführt" verwendet.